# Can't add a MouseListener to PApplet

Tags: java, mouseevent, processing, mouselistener, mouse-listeners

I'm currently working on a previously written application using `PApplet`.
I need my class to append a mouse listener to the `PApplet`. I simply gave my class a reference to its parent `PApplet` and wrote

```
parent.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    //Implementation
}
```

But the parent does not seem to know any thing about my event.

Then, for testing, I tried to add the event directly to the setup method of the PApplet using this code:

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    }
});
```

It gives my the compile error:

> "The method addMouseListener(MouseListener) in the type Component is
>   not applicable for the arguments new (MouseAdapter(){})".

I tried the same code with a newly created class extends from `PApplet`, and it works.

I wonder where could be the error?

Comment: That error doesn't look right. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows exactly what code you're running? Can you post the exact text of the error? What version of Processing are you using?

Comment: What version of Processing?  Processing 3 does not extend Applet anymore. Though I don't know if this could be issue  https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0